# Trace Page-level Memory Accesses of a process

Tags: linux, valgrind, trace, perf, memory-profiling

I am currently trying to trace all DRAM accesses of a Process. I am interested in obtaining detailed traces of the data accesses that missed the last level of processor hardware cache and result in main memory accesses.

My ideal trace file would look like this :
Timestamp , Physical Memory Address , Virtual Memory Address , Operation (Load or store) , hit or miss

The tools I have already considered are Intel VTune , perf mem , and valgrind.
I couldn't find a way to use Intel VTune to find such information and the same goes for perf mem. I am pretty sure there is a way to create such trace with valgrind but the output files and the runtimes are enormous.
I have also considered checking periodically the Page Table - access bit customly, and create a trace file with Virtual Addresses but that would later require a creation of cache simulation to obtain the information I want. (Seems like too much work and I wish I could avoid that)

What I want to ask if there is a way to obtain such trace? Or if there is no such way, is there a way to obtain somewhat similar information that I could use for memory access pattern prediction (on page level) ?

Comment: Pretty sure gem5 or maybe cachegrind could *simulate* a CPU with caches.  For Intel PMU hardware, perf list on my Skylake mentions `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` -  *[Retired load instructions missed L3 cache as data sources **Supports address when precise** (Precise event)]*.  I'm pretty sure that's talking about logging the data load/store address with the event, not the RIP of the load instruction, so yes there is HW support for logging this.  Hopefully `perf record` has some existing support for doing this.  From the man page, that *might* be what `perf record --data` does?

Comment: @Peter this functionality only *samples* a small subset of accesses and AFAIK this limitation is built into the hardware. See PEBS load latency and precise store for more info.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: oh right, of course, it only records the address when it takes a sample, not for every access.  Derp.

Comment: To be clear, this "sampling" isn't the normal software-driven sampling that you get with say perf record, but rather random sampling built into the PMU specifically for this feature. I.e. a random set of accesses are tagged for sampling (AFAIK you can't adjust the fraction) and then recorded in the PEBS data if they meet the filter criteria. Later, software like perf will read the accumulated samples. @Peter